# What is the difference between CRect c; and CRect c(); when CRect is a class?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between CRect c; and CRect c(), when CRect is a class?

Comment: (Careful with the duplicates - I hasty-clicked it too :-/)

Comment: @pst: Yeah, I pretty much copied the wrong link. :-/ Massive fail on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one

```
CRect c;
```

creates a `CRect` object called `c`.

This one

```
CRect c();
```

declares a function called `c()` that returns a `CRect` object. It is a parse that is vexing, however, it isn't the [most vexing one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 6):

```
CRect c;
```

defines an object

```
CRect c();
```

declares a function returns `CRect` object.

Sometimes people are not aware of second form and get caught by [most vexing parse.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)